# Is there a way to get JSON.Net to serialize an object using implicit conversion instead of its actual type?

Tags: c#, json.net, implicit-conversion

Consider this interface and classes...

```
public interface IValueHolder{}

public class ValueHolder<TValue> : IValueHolder {

    public ValueHolder(TValue value) => this.value = value;
    public TValue value { get; }

    public static implicit operator ValueHolder<TValue>(TValue value) => new ValueHolder<TValue>(value);
    public static implicit operator TValue(ValueHolder<TValue> valueHolder) => valueHolder.value;
}

class ValueStorage : Dictionary<string, IValueHolder>{}
```

Note the implicit conversions to and from `TValue`.

The point of this code is I'm trying to store key/value pairs where the value can be any type, but without having boxing penalties. This is possible since I will always know the type when setting or retrieving the value from the storage. (That's why I didn't just use `Dictionary<string, object>`.)

Now consider this code...

```
var storage = new ValueStorage();

storage["UltimateQuestion"] = new ValueHolder<string>("What do you get when you multiply six by nine?");
storage["UltimateAnswer"] = new ValueHolder<int>(42);

var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings{
    TypeNameHandling  = TypeNameHandling.None,
    Formatting        = Formatting.Indented,
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
};

var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(storage, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

The result is this...

```
{
    "UltimateQuestion": {
        "value": "What do you get when you multiply six by nine?"
    },
    "UltimateAnswer": {
        "value": 42
    }
}
```

I was hoping with the implicit conversion to and from `TValue`, which are `string` and `int` respectively, it would give me this...

```
{
    "UltimateQuestion": "What do you get when you multiply six by nine?",
    "UltimateAnswer": 42
}
```

So how can I get `ValueStorage<T>` to serialize and deserialize as `T`?  I don't mind writing custom converters (provided they're generic and can be based on `TValue`) or custom `SettingsContractResolver` subclasses, but I'm not sure where to start.

### Update

The more I think about this, the more I think this isn't actually solvable.  This is because while serialization is easy, the deserialization would need to know the types for `TValue`, which aren't stored in the JSON in the format that I want, therefore it *can't* be deserialized. (Even the original output above with the nested objects has the same issue. You need the type information for this to work in any capacity.)

However, as not to keep this question open, what about a converter that stores the type information for `TValue` instead of `ValueHolder<TValue>`?

e.g.

```
{
    "UltimateQuestion": {
        "$type": "[Whatever TValue is--string here]",
        "value": "What do you get when you multiply six by nine?"
    },
    "UltimateAnswer": {
        "$type": "[Whatever TValue is--int here]",
        "value": 42
    }
}
```

That way the converter could reconstruct `ValueHolder<TValue>` instances during deserialization.  It's not perfect, but would at least allow proper deserialization without exposing the ValueHolder framework.

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is -- "Can I make a `dynamic` method without boxing unboxing." Even the ans provided by ckuri still cannot avoid the process that assigning variable as `object` (still boxing unboxing). I do believe it can't be done. But interesting, let's see if someone expert to explain it.

Comment: Well I don't mind if you box/unbox during (de)serialization. I just don't want that happening during the regular reads/writes to the store, hence this framework.  Serialization, kind of by definition, isn't going to be performant.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a converter (see https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm).

```
public class ValueHolderJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
      serializer.Serialize(writer, ((IValueHolder)value).value);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
      return Activator.CreateInstance(objectType, serializer.Deserialize(reader));
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(IValueHolder).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }
}
```

Please not that I added a non-generic "value" property to your interface to get the values regardless of the actual generic type without needing to use reflection:

```
public interface IValueHolder{
   object value { get; }
}

public class ValueHolder<TValue> : IValueHolder
{
    // as before

    object IValueHolder.value => (object)value;
}
```

To use it you create a new JsonSerializerSettings class (or append your existing one):

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
    Converters = {
        new ValueHolderJsonConverter()
    };
```

And provide it as parameter to SerializeObject and DeserializeObject.

Comment: This looked promising! It serialized correctly, but it doesn't deserialize correctly.  However, I think this clarified that what I'm trying to do isn't actually possible as the desired JSON format doesn't store the type info which would be needed for `TValue` when reconstruct the `ValueHolder<TValue>` instances for the dictionary. I think this proves I instead need to serialize concrete types with properties instead of a dictionary.

Comment: That said, I'm going to try one other thing in your converter.  I'm going to use the JSON property to try and get the type info. It only has to be compatible with what I need. Not hopeful, but we'll see!